# Why is the "required" attribute ignored when using recaptcha?

Tags: php, html, forms, invisible-recaptcha

On below script, the form uses the `required` attribute for a checkbox, yet it is possible to send it without checking the box. According to [w3cschool](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp), all current browser support this attribute.
Why doesn't it work ?

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js' async defer></script>
                <script>
                  function onTosSubmit(token) {
                    document.getElementById("tos").submit();
                  }
                </script>
                <noscript><?php echo 'enable JS'; ?></noscript>
                <form id='tos' action="" method="POST">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="toscheckbox" id="toscheckbox" required/>
                    <label for="toscheckbox">I agree with terms of use</label>
                    <button
                        class="g-recaptcha"
                        data-sitekey="My Google reCaptcha API key"
                        data-callback="onTosSubmit">
                        Button text
                    </button>
                </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Removing the button attributes allows proper operation, but they are required for recaptcha.

Comment: Legal issues, there must be a checkbox for the end user to check.

Comment: I will go out on a limb and say it is because the `required` attribute comes into play with the form is sumitted, where as your form is never really "submitted", it has a javascript event called on the click of a `Button`. Perhaps the data-callback should have validation implemented for the required field, in javascript.

Comment: you can use javascript to stop the sending of the form, but if JS is switched of on users browser it won't work. But you of course have to do back end checking to if it's legal issues

Comment: You should be validating this server-side anyways. A client-side TOS acceptance that isn't validated server-side is worthless on a legal level.

Comment: while server-side validation on this is ABSOLUTELY necessary in this case, there is nothing wrong with having client side validation as well as it adds the benefit of reducing incomplete requests to the server and server side processing required.

Comment: Checking server side is not part of the question and is a separate matter.